# Navigation in Xamarin Forms with Custom Movement between pages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Hi Xamarin Developers,

So I have one requirement  where user go From Page1 -> Page2 -> Page3 -> Page4 and after Page4, He has to return back to Page2 and If he press back button he should navigate it back to Page1.

How to achieve this in Xamarin Forms.?

I tried like this,

```
 Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]);
               _ = Navigation.PopAsync(true);
```

But it's giving weird animation and not working properly.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: If you are using

```
Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]);
```

from **page4**, `Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1 = 3`, which is the index of **page4** in the `NavigationStack` (**page1** has index 0!).

I think you should use

```
Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
```

instead...

---

Further comments:

### Using Shell/Xamarin.Forms 4.0

**Shell**, available from **Xamarin.Forms 4.0**, is meant to easy the management of `Navigation` in an Application. **XF 4.0** ships in a couple of weeks, so maybe it would be worth to wait for it ([**X.F 4.0** is at the moment in pre-release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.0/4.0.0-pre10), and you can use **Shell** features now if you want to give it a chance!).

### The traditional way

a) In order to go back to the first page (root page) you can use

```
Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
```

b) In order to pop from **page4** to **page2**, i also use the technique with `Navigation.RemovePage`, but with the difference that i perform this removal immediately after i `PushAsync` to **page4**, so once you call `PopAsync()` from **page4**, it pops directly to **page2** without having to remove anything at that time (see code below). Please try it this way and let me know if you succeed :)

```
private async Task PushMyPage4RemovingCurrentPageFromNavigationStack()
{
    var currentPage = ((NavigationPage)mainPage).CurrentPage as MyPage3;

    await currentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage4());

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // At this point MyPage4 is already pushed, so it is now the CurrentPage.
        var newCurrentPage = ((NavigationPage)mainPage).CurrentPage;

        IReadOnlyList<Page> navStack = newCurrentPage.Navigation.NavigationStack;

        // If not moved to main thread in iOS we get:
        //
        // UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException: UIKit Consistency error: you are 
        // calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.
        //
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => newCurrentPage.Navigation.RemovePage(navStack[navStack.Count - 2]));

        else

            newCurrentPage.Navigation.RemovePage(navStack[navStack.Count - 2]);
    });

}
```